# Popup program execution - python

Tags: python, user-interface, popup

I need a simple popup that indicates the execution of the program and disappears when finished. It should only serve to indicate to the user that the script is running. I have PySimpleGUI.

Comment: Show your code attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will popup a window.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.popup('This is my popup message')
```

Do you want it to "block", waiting for the user to click OK?
You can also have it autoclose after a while.
Or, you can make it not-block and your program will immediately continue executing.

It's all described in the [PySimpleGUI documentation](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org) under the Popup section.

Here's is code that will show the Popup window.  Your program will NOT block on it and will thus continue running immediately

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.popup_non_blocking('This is my popup message')
print('My program continued')
```

When the program is done running, the window will disappear.

The plain popup function also has a parameter to indicate if you want it to be a non-blocking call that you can use instead of the popup_non_blocking function.  The popup_non_blocking function calls popup with this parameter set for you.

Comment: This is a really simple solution that does exactly what was asked for. Thank you!